# Undefined cryptojs when importing crypto-js in Nest Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, cryptojs

I am importing crypto-js in a Nestjs service, and I run into this error

---

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'enc')
at CryptoUtilsService.decryptAESHex

---

The code:

```
import { Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CmacDto, Crc32Dto } from './dto';
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
import { AesDecryptDto } from './dto/aesDecrypt.dto';

@Injectable()
export class CryptoUtilsService {
    private readonly logger = new Logger(CryptoUtilsService.name);
    
    decryptAESHex(data: AesDecryptDto) {
        let keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(data.key);
        let ivHex = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(data.iv);

        let encryptedWordArray = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(
            data.encryptedData.toUpperCase(),
        );

        let encString = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(encryptedWordArray);
        // console.log("before decryption: ", encryptedString.toUpperCase(), encString);

        let decryptedResp = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encString, keyHex, {
            iv: ivHex,
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
            padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding,
        });
        // console.log("after decryption:: ", decryptedResp)

        return CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(decryptedResp).toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

I have installed crypto-js and @types/crypto-js module. Also tried deleting the node_modules and installing again.
It seems to work fine on other node projects without typescript. I cannot figure out what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

[`crypto-js` doesn't use default exports for its base package](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/crypto-js/index.d.ts), use `import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js'` to import the package correctly

Comment: Thank you. This solved it. But I used the same import statement when I used it with react native. How are they different and how do I know when a lib is not using default exports. Both codes donot contain 'export default CryptoJs'

Comment: Your react native code, if in Typescript, probably has `esModuleInterop` true in the `tsconfig.json`. That sets `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` to `true` which makes default imports work even with non-default export packages. To know if a package uses default exports, you can either check their docs or their `d.ts` file. It looks like `crypto-js`'s sub folder _do_ use default exports, but their main export is not a default one